# HIVE query for HAVING and Distinct

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have below Hive table

```
accountNum  date  status  action qty time
    ----------  ----  ------  ------ --- ----
    1234        2017   filled  B      10  11:20
    1234        2017   filled  S      10  11:20
    2345        2017   filled  B      20  12:00
    2345        2017   filled  B      10  12:00
    4444        2017   filled  B       5  01:00
    4444        2017   filled  S       5  02:00
```

Here I want to compare 2 rows with action "B" and then action "S". If found 2 rows with first B and then S on those records I have to check accountNum,date,time,status is same.

So based on above test data I should get only first 2 rows

```
accountNum  date  status  action qty time
----------  ----  ------  ------ --- ----
1234        2017   filled  B      10  11:20
1234        2017   filled  S      10   11:20
```

For this what type of query I should write?

I have mysql query for this as below but HIVE doesnot support HAVING/DISTINCT/COUNT so it will not work in HIVE .. is there anyway to use HAVING or any way to use JOIN and write query ?

```
select  t1.*
from    yourTable t1
join    (
            select  accountNum, date, status, time
            from    yourTable
            where   action in ('B', 'S')
            group by accountNum, date, status, time
            having  count(distinct action) = 2
        ) t2
on      t1.accountNum = t2.accountNum and
        t1.date = t2.date and
        t1.status = t2.status and
        t1.time = t2.time
```

Comment: Do records always come in pairs for a given account number?

Comment: yes it comes in pair and first is B and then S

Comment: Can the same account pair appear more than once in the data set, e.g. in two different blocks of two records?

Comment: yes same account pair can appear more than once in data set

Comment: "HIVE does not support HAVING/DISTINCT/COUNT"?!

Comment: Can anyone please help or only asking questions !!:)

Answer (score 0):

#### 1.

`date` is a reserved word.

#### 2.

There seems to be a limitation regarding the use of expressions in the `HAVING` clause if they don't appear in the `SELECT` clause.

**This query (based on your original query) works:**

```
select  t1.*
from    yourTable t1
join    (
            select  accountNum, date, status, time,count(distinct action)
            from    yourTable
            where   action in ('B', 'S')
            group by accountNum, `date`, status, time
            having  count(distinct action) = 2
        ) t2
on      t1.accountNum = t2.accountNum and
        t1.`date` = t2.`date` and
        t1.status = t2.status and
        t1.time = t2.time
```

---

```
+------------+------+--------+--------+-----+-------+
| accountnum | date | status | action | qty | time  |
+------------+------+--------+--------+-----+-------+
|       1234 | 2017 | filled | B      |  10 | 11:20 |
|       1234 | 2017 | filled | S      |  10 | 11:20 |
+------------+------+--------+--------+-----+-------+
```

**Here is another solution based on windows functions**

```
select  accountnum,`date`,status,action,qty,time

from   (select  *
               ,max(case when action = 'B' then 1 end) over w as b_flag
               ,max(case when action = 'S' then 1 end) over w as s_flag
           
        from    yourTable

        where   action in ('B', 'S')

        window  w as (partition by  accountNum, `date`, status, time)
        ) t
        
where   b_flag = 1
    and s_flag = 1
;
```

---

```
+------------+------+--------+--------+-----+-------+
| accountnum | date | status | action | qty | time  |
+------------+------+--------+--------+-----+-------+
|       1234 | 2017 | filled | B      |  10 | 11:20 |
|       1234 | 2017 | filled | S      |  10 | 11:20 |
+------------+------+--------+--------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: But in HIVE with first query as you said with HAVING/DSTINCT it is giving me below error                          Your query has the following error(s):

Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

Comment: Is there any simple query with Join and all.. all I need is to fetch same day Buy (B ) and sell(S) action by an account number

Comment: No sorry this is not what I want because my result set should give me in pair of B and S but now the result out of query is coming only S. this is not what I am trying to get. As mentioned all other column values should match with pair of B and S in action column.

Comment: In my answer you can see the actual execution results for your sample. For both queries you can see both `B` and `S`. Furthermore, the first query is **your** query with 2 technical fixes that enables it to run.